# Timer just runs the first time

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all I am a complete noobie when it comes to python. Actually I started reading about it this morning when I needed to use it, so sorry if the code is a disaster.

I'd like to get this done:
A communication via serial between two devices. The device where the python program is running has to be listening for some data being sent by the other device and storing it in a file. But every 30 seconds of received data it has to send a command to the other device to tell it to stop sending and begin a scan that takes 10 seconds.

This is the code I've written. It's printing continuously Opening connection..

```
    from serial import Serial
    from threading import Timer
    import time


    MOVE_TIME = 30.0
    SCAN_TIME = 10.0
    DEVICE_ADDRESS = '/dev/ttyACM0'
    BAUD_RATE = 9600

    while True:
        try:
            print("Opening connection...")
            ser = Serial(DEVICE_ADDRESS, BAUD_RATE
            break

        except SerialException:
            print("No device attached")


    def scan():
        print("Scanning...")
        timeout = time.time() + SCAN_TIME

        while True:
            #Some code I haven't thought of yet
            if time.time() > timeout:
                ser.write(b'r') #command to start
                break


    def send_stop_command():
        print("Sending stop command")
        ser.write(b's') #command to stop
        scan()

    t = Timer(MOVE_TIME + SCAN_TIME, send_stop_command)
    t.start()

    filename = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S") + ".txt"

    while True:
        data = ser.readline()
        try:
            with open(filename, "ab") as outfile:
                outfile.write(data)
                outfile.close()
        except IOError:
            print("Data could not be written")
```

Comment: If you do not have actual problem with code, and need review, it is better to ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @myaut:  This isn't something that would fall on topic at Code Review, though.

Comment: @myaut: I haven't been able to test it yet. I don't have the devices at hand.  It wasn't about a faulty code per se(though it may be the case)  but commenting your point of view on how to code it, cause my implementation could be wrong from the beginning.

Comment: You left the quotes around r open at line 21

Comment: @ÁlvaroRamiro: Unfortunately it is hard to answer such questions because they are opinion based. I.e. someone may prefer Twisted because it is cool, so such questions are falling out of StackOverflow's scope. You need __testing__, which can be Code Review, or System Testing (in your case it is "simulator" of device). If you need advise on how to design it, there is Programmers.

Comment: @myaut, I've updated the code and test it just sending every 1 sec from the other device a string. It doesn't create the file.
I've tried the code of the openfile and write with local data and it does create the file and write it.
It doesn't catch a exception creating the serial connection.
The other device is an arduino that does Serial.print every second.

Comment: I've been able to establish the connection, receive the data, open the file, write the data. The problem I'm encountering is that the function that the timer calls is just called the first time. After that it's never called again.